# Get leading characters of a string before the first occurrence of a pipe character

Tags: php, regex

i'm trying to learn a bit about regex, can anyone explain to me what is going on here? And   give example on a regex that would provide the expected output? Thanks!

```
input data = 'Sometext|even more text'

regex = '(.*)?\|?.*'

replacement = '$1'

expected output = 'Sometext'

actual output = 'Sometext|even more text'
```

PHP

```
preg_filter("(.*)?\|?.*", "$1", 'Sometext|even more text'); // returns  Sometext|even more text
```

Comment: Please add you PHP code as well.

Comment: `\|?` also makes the vertical bar optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*)` is greedy, so matches everything. `$1` is everything then.

You are probably looking for:

```
/^([^|]*).*$/
```

Comment: And what would a non greedy (.*) look like?

Comment: @netbrain: `(.*?)` but it's better to avoid the match-all operator and instead exclude characters you don't want to match, like @hakre did.

Comment: You make it non-greedy by adding a `?`. However, I edited the answer because you don't want to understand but just to have code ;)

Comment: I'd like to know exactly what this `[^|]` does? matches everything up until |?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is saying "all chars, followed by an optional `|`, followed by 0 or more chars".

Change the initial `(.*)` to `([^\|]*)`, or make the `|` non-optional.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is greedy, which means it will try to match as much text as possible. In this case:

- `(.*)?` will match all the text
- `\|?.*` will match the "rest" (empty string)

try: `regex = '\|[^|]*', replacement = ''`

Answer (score 1):

If you change your regex to `(\w+)?\|?.*`, specifically adding the `+` after the `\w` then you will get your expected answer of 'Sometext'.

The reason you were having the whole string match is that the first `.*` was matching the whole string.  With the changes I have above, you will be matching on any word character.